# Convert Problem to a Linear Programming (Piecewise Functions)

Tags: convex-optimization, linear-programming

I want to write the following problem as a linear program:

$$minimize_x \sum_{i=0}^m{h_w(a_i^Tx-b_i)}$$
$$
h_w(u) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            |x| & \quad |u| \leq w \\
            w+(|x|-w)^2 & \quad |u| > w
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$

Here is my attempt:

first, write it in the epigraph form (and because each term is positive we can separate terms):
$$minimize_{x,t}\;1^Tt$$
$${h_w(a_i^Tx-b_i)} \leq t_i\:\forall i=0,..,m$$
Which could lead to:
$$minimize_{x,t}\;1^Tt$$
$$ -t_i \leq{x} \leq t_i\:\forall i=0,..,m$$
$$ (|x|-w)^2  \leq {(t_i-w)}\:\forall i=0,..,m$$

I don't know how to make it simpler. Is there anyway to find out a problem could convert to an LP or not?

Comment: a quadratic function cannot be made linear, at least not without making a piecewise linear approximation

Comment: Just graph the objective function for the case where there's only one variable- it's not piecewise linear.